# Add array of file names in Magick::ImageList

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array that contains multiple file names of images.

file_name = ["/tmp/image_1.tiff","/tmp/image_2.tiff"]

When I do this operation **Magick::ImageList.new(file_name)**, I get the following error message.

> Magick::ImageMagickError Exception: unable to open image
>   `'/home/tmp/image_1.tiff','/home/tmp/image_2.tiff'': No such file or
>   directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.

How to call multiple image files in a single imagelist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if the file exists, using `File.realpath("/tmp/image_1.tiff")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Magick::ImageList.new(*file_name)
```

With the * (or "splat") operator you can turn an Array into an argument list. When applied in your case you get:

```
Magick::ImageList.new(*["/tmp/image_1.tiff","/tmp/image_2.tiff"])
```